# How to Make List of List

Tags: c#, arraylist, nested

I trying to make something like English spelling/grammar checker program. I have no ideas how to write list of list for the correct suggestion option.
http://www.polishmywriting.com/
example:

**Error:1**
suggestion1
suggestion2
suggestion3

**error:2**
suggestion1
suggesiton2
suggestion3

**error:3**
suggestion1
suggesiton2

and so on depend number of error you got.

any ideas how can i write?

Comment: This question is quite vague. It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Feel free to ask a question about a specific problem, but without more information we can't really provide you with any sort of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create list of lists in C# using below code

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>();
myList.Add(new List<string> { "a", "b" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "c", "d", "e" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "qwerty", "asdf", "zxcv" });
myList.Add(new List<string> { "a", "b" });

// To iterate over it.
foreach (List<string> subList in myList)
{
    foreach (string item in subList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```